# Getting undefined when trying to pass data between component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all I am new in React. I have two components `TagUtils` and `Urls`. I am trying to pass router paramter from `Urls` to `TagUtils`. Here is  my codes:

Urls.jsx

```
// some codes....
export default class Urls extends React.Component {

render() {
 return (
   <div>
        <TagUtils  tag={this.props.params.tag_id}/>
   </div>
)
}
}
```

TagUtils.jsx

```
export default class TagUtils extends React.Component {

    deleteTag(props) {
        console.log(props.tag);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteTag}><i className="fa fa-trash"> Delete</i></button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When I clicked Delete button it just showing `undefined` .Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: can you see this.props.params.tag_id in the console if you log it? You should be using this.props.tag_id, and you need to be setting tag_Id somewhere, can we see that code?

Comment: React es6 classe docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the shift of React from createClass to `ES6 classes` we need to handle the correct value of `this` to our methods on our own, as mentioned here: http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes
Change your code to have the method bounded to correct value of this in constructor:

```
export default class TagUtils extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.deleteTag = this.deleteTag.bind(this);
  }

  deleteTag(props) {
    console.log(props.tag);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteTag}><i className="fa fa-trash"> Delete</i></button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The `no autobinding` was a deliberate step from React guys for ES6 classes. Autobinding to correct context was provided with `React.createClass`. Details of this can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding

So based on this you could also change your code as:

```
export default class TagUtils extends React.Component {
  deleteTag = (props) => {
    console.log(props.tag);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteTag}><i className="fa fa-trash"> Delete</i></button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example `props` is `event` Object where there is no `tag` property - that's why you are getting `undefined`., you need set `this` for `deleteTag` and then you can get component `props` through `this.props` inside `deleteTag` method

```
export default class TagUtils extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     this.deleteTag = this.deleteTag.bind(this);
  } 

  deleteTag() {
    console.log(this.props.tag);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteTag}>
          <i className="fa fa-trash"> Delete</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```